# Is there a way in Javascript to gradually update elements and not update all at the same time

Tags: javascript, html, loops, for-loop, delay

Let's say I have a html grid of 100 span elements and I want to gradully change the colour of these spans from span[0] to span[100]. My code below changes the colour of the span elements but all in one hit, and then again after 3 seconds but does not do what I'm after. Ideally I would like it gradually change the colours then after 3 seconds start changing them again whilst the first function keeps changing to the end of span[100]

```js
var count = 1;
var ancestor = document.getElementById('hello');
var descendents = ancestor.getElementsByTagName('span');
var myColors = ['rgb(146, 168, 209)', 'rgb(136, 176, 75)', 'rgb(247, 202, 201)'];
var e, c;

function myLoop(count) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    for (i = 0; i < descendents.length; ++i) {
      e = descendents[i];
      c = e.style.color;
      //pick color
      e.style.color = myColors[Math.floor(Math.random() * myColors.length)];
    }
    count++;
    if (count < descendents.length) {
      myLoop(count);
    }
  }, 3000);
}
myLoop(count);
```

Comment: can you provide the code with HTML in jsfiddle or codepen?

Answer (score 0):

The code below could use some improving and syntax sugar to be smaller, but I think that's what you are looking for. In this snippet I created only 10 spans and set the interval to 250m just to be easier to test. What it will do is start from span 1 and go until 10 changing the colors to the first one in `myColors` array. After it finishes, it will begin again from the second color and so forth.

In your code you used `setTimeout`, that will run once after 3s and then not run again. I think that you were looking for `setInterval`, which will create a loop that runs every X miliseconds.

```js
const myColors = ['rgb(146, 168, 209)', 'rgb(136, 176, 75)', 'rgb(247, 202, 201)'];
let index = 0;
let loops = 0;

function generateSpans(){
  const ancestor = document.getElementById("ancestor");
  for(let i = 0; i<10; i++){
    const span = document.createElement("span");
    span.innerText = i;
    ancestor.appendChild(span);
  }
}

function blinkElements(){
  const elements = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
  setInterval(function(){
    if(index === elements.length){
      index = 0;
      if(loops === myColors.length-1){
        loops = 0;
      }else{
        loops++;
      }
    }
    elements[index].style.backgroundColor = myColors[loops];
    index++;
  }, 250);
}


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    generateSpans();
    blinkElements();
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 50px;
}

span {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="ancestor">
</div>
```